# SQLAlchemy.orm. Combine Columns 'First', 'Middle', 'Last' to create Column 'full_name'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am on day three of learning SQLAlchemy.  Reading O'Reilly Essential SQLAlchemy 2nd Edition and searching the internet for this.  Not sure I have the correct wording to find my answer unfortunately.

I am trying to create a table "Person" that has a persons first, middle, and last name.  I want to use those three columns to create a fourth column 'full_name'.  I would like to have the full_name have index=True and unique=True.

This will ultimately be a family tree type of program.  Column 'father' will be the relationship to people.full_name.

Any guidance from someone with more than three days of experience is very appreciated.

Here is my model thus far.

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'people'

    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    first = Column(String(50), nullable=False)
    middle = Column(String(30))
    last = Column(String(25), nullable=False)
    maiden = Column(String(25), nullable=True)
    full_name = Column(String(), index=True, unique=True)  # This column is where I am stuck.
    gender = Column(String(10), index=True, nullable=False)
    birth = Column(String(10))
    birth_place = Column(String(30))
    death = Column(String(30))
    death_place = Column(String(30))
    marriage_date = Column(String(10))
    divorce_date = Column(String(10))

    father = Column(String, ForeignKey('people.full_name'))
    mother = Column(String, ForeignKey('people.full_name'))
    spouce = Column(String, ForeignKey('people.full_name'))

    created_on = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now)
    updated_on = Column(DateTime(), default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Person '{self.full_name}'>"
```

Comment: i don't work in SQLAlchemy often enough, but look into the keyword arguments `default=` and `on_update=` because you can 1. supply the value for the inserted rows with `default`, and 2. ensure it gets updated if any of the name parts get changed by an UPDATE query.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/defaults.html#computed-columns-generated-always-as

Comment: Thank you both. I think you pointed me in the right direction.